# How to add dynamic hyperlink in RDLC report wizard c# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, rdlc

I want to add a dynamic hyperlink on click (action)  on client Name with hyperlink expression value of url i.e. Dataset field. Dataset is retrieving the data but Fields!.url.Value doesn't retrieve value also field is not clickable. That means i am using wrong syntax. I have inserted static link and it's working.
Any help will be appreciable Thanks.

[This is the report, i am retrieving it's data from data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju61g.png)

[This the dataset that contains the url field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvLWy.png)

[this the expression i want to set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgx0y.png)

Comment: A RDLC Report is a file with an extension rdlc and is a Webpage (HTML format).  Any webpage (URL) is a file on a machine where the file is accessible with a webrowser.  So does your URL (file) exist?

Comment: No i am using it in reportviewer, Windows Application C#

Comment: All report viewer does is create and rdlc file which you could do manually.  It is like a windows form project that automatically generates designer.csfile.  You can open the rdlc file with not pad to see contents.  I modified a rdlc without using a viewer.  I opened file with notepad and copied the COMMAND_TEXT and pasted into SQL Server Management Studio.  Then got changes working in SSMS.  When done I pasted the COMMAND_TEXT back into the rdlc file.

Comment: Can you share what COMMAND_TEXT you have inserted to achieve this?

Comment: A RDLC Report is really just a webpage that you view with a browser.  The webpage has a URL which is linked to a file with an extension RDLC.  The URL has optional parameters which are after a question mark and when you have multiple parameters there are separated by an ampersand  So if you want a dynamic hyperlink you want to add parameters to the URL.  See : http://dotnetknowledgebox.blogspot.com/2012/01/passing-parameters-to-rdlc.html?force_isolation=true